# Excel drop down list to convert full name & enter Abbreviations

Tags: vba, excel

I have a database called Overtime with a second sheet called data. On the first sheet I am using data validation to access the data list on the data page. At present The list has peoples full names. What I want to do is when a name is selected it then changes it to the Initials from the Data sheet. Not sure if this can be done into the one cell, or to use something like Vlookup to enter the initials into an adjacent cell. The names and Initials are on the same rows on the data page (in columns "I" & "J"). On the main database the validation list is for column "O". I have a column "P" ready to put in the formula to show the initials if this the only way it can be done.

Comment: Use vlooklup or an index/match pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in the `Data` sheet like:

[image]

In **P1** enter:

```
=IF(OR(O1="",NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(O1,Data!I:I,0)))),"",VLOOKUP(O1,Data!I:J,2,FALSE))
```

and copy down.

Comment: Thanks for the formula @Gary's Student, it works with only one minor glitch. It puts the initials into the next row down! So the name Darth Vader is in cell O2, but the intials DV are in P3. Can you advise what I need to do to get it to work on the same line please?

Comment: @IanMartin  Very strange!!.............I am assuming the data and tables all start with row **#1** .............perhaps an adjustment is required...........

Comment: Just found out what needed to be changed. Just set the Vlookup to start from line 2 and it works fine!